# Spring MockMvc Did not find handler method

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I've added validation to the classes in an app that provides REST APIs and I'm trying to restructure the unit tests to use MockMvc so that the validation will be called.  I've seen several tutorials on setting this up, but whenever I try and make a call to one of the APIs, I get a 404 empty response and the log files indicate "Did not find handler method for /xxxxx".

There's probably just something I'm missing in either the XML configuration file or the test class, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Test Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring_test.xml")
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ClientControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private static final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

    @Mock
    StorageProvider       storageProvider;

    @Mock
    ClientCriteria        clientCriteria;

    @Mock
    UserPermissionChecker userPermissionChecker;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws BusinessException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        String identityUserToken = "TEST USER";
        Mockito.when(userPermissionChecker.checkPermissions(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(identityUserToken);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockMvc() throws Exception {
        String clientId = "1";
        String channel = "internet";
        String market = "canada";
        String transactionStyle = "blah";
        String featureSet = "blah_blah";

        Client requestedClient = new Client(clientId, channel, market, transactionStyle, featureSet);

        ServletContext sc = webApplicationContext.getServletContext();
        assertNotNull(sc);
        assertTrue(sc instanceof MockServletContext);

        ResultActions ra = mockMvc.perform(post("/myapibase/v1/clients")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(requestedClient))
        );

        ra.andDo(print());
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myapibase/v1")
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    private StorageProvider       storageProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserPermissionChecker userPermissionChecker;

    private String                baseUrl;

    private static Logger         log                          = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    public ClientController(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clients", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addClient(@RequestBody @Valid Client clientToAdd, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParams) {
        String methodName = "addClient";

    ...
    }
```

XML Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>-->

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:ValidationMessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageAccessor" class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableServiceFoundation
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp.controllers", "com.myapp.models", "com.myapp.storage", "com.myapp.managers",
        "com.myapp.txyz", "com.myapp.util", })
public class Application {

    ...
}
```

Log Output:

```
22:04:30.866 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
22:04:30.870 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
22:04:30.871 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
22:04:30.871 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@1f7076bc]
22:04:30.871 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet '' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.]
22:04:30.871 [main] INFO  o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 38 ms
22:04:30.872 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Servlet '' configured successfully
22:04:30.978 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing POST request for [/myapibase/v1/clients]
22:04:30.981 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /myapibase/v1/clients
22:04:30.982 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/myapibase/v1/clients]
22:04:30.982 [main] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapibase/v1/clients] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
22:04:30.983 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /myapibase/v1/clients
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}

             Handler:
                Type = null

               Async:
       Async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = null

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 404
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

Comment: which Spring/Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: spring boot is 1.2.5, spring is 4.1.7